# Rails 5: How to send and process large files (200Mb) via Rails API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for the general concept, but every tip can be useful. The client (mobile) has to send a large file to Rails API. It's a some text file with raw data.

How can the Rails API get the large file from client? Should it be done by HTTP request, websockets? Should the files be sent in chunks?

Comment: Do you have control over the client implementation?

Comment: Yes, I have the control

Answer (score 1):

You need to use EventMachine based server I think.  It is possible to see implememntation and use cases of [json-stream](https://github.com/dgraham/json-stream) as example. The json-stream is used for processing large json files.